# Joining two dictionaries

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I have two Dictionaries and I need to find a way to join them together.Here are the two dictionary types.

```
IDictionary<string, byte[]> dictionary1
IDictionary<IFileShareDocument, string> dictionary2
```

Out of this two dictionaries I have to create a third dictionary that will look like this

```
IDictionary<IFileShareDocument, byte[]> dictionary3
```

Both dictionaries have the exact same number of items and the string property of both them is the linking point.

What I would like is to be able to write something that would do somethign like this:

```
dictionary1.value join with dictionary2.key
where dictionary1.key == dictionary2.value

This statement should result in dictionary3.
```

Is there any way I can achieve this I can not seem to find a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it using the LINQ query syntax, with `join` (this compiles to roughly the same thing as @KingKing's solution):

```
IDictionary<IFileShareDocument, byte[]> dictionary3 =
    (from item1 in dictionary1
     join item2 in dictionary2 on item1.Key equals item2.Value
     select new { item2.Key, item1.Value })
         .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Note that the above is greatly preferred to this example using `from` and `where`, because it is more efficient. I'm including this here because if you're like me (more familiar with SQL, which would convert something like this to a join automatically), this poor way might be the first one that comes to mind:

```
IDictionary<IFileShareDocument, byte[]> dictionary3 =
    (from item1 in dictionary1
     from item2 in dictionary2
     where item1.Key == item2.Value
     select new { item2.Key, item1.Value })
         .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: The first solution will perform *dramatically* worse than the second solution.  A Join is O(N + M), a Cartesian Product is O(N * M).  There isn't any real advantage to the Cartesian Product at all, assuming you actually want a Join, so long as the relevant keys already have sensible hash code and equality implementations (which they do).

Comment: @Servy thanks for pointing that out; I've swapped my solutions and included a note saying why `join` is better.

Comment: Why include the other solution at all?  It has no advantages, only disadvantages.  What is to be gained by having it there?

Comment: For the same reason that counterexamples and anti-patterns can be worth mentioning. Someone like me who is more familiar with SQL than LINQ might be tempted to do it that way (that's all I included at first), without realizing that LINQ isn't intelligent enough to convert that into an intelligent Join.

Answer (score 5):

```
var dictionary3 =
    dictionary1
        .Join(dictionary2, x => x.Key, x => x.Value, (x, y) => new { x, y })
        .ToDictionary(a => a.y.Key, a => a.x.Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Would this work for you?

```
var result =
    dictionary2
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => dictionary1[x.Value]);
```